# Input string was not in correct format. Handle exception 

Tags: c#, validation, properties

I get the exception "Input string was not in correct format". I want to handle that exception and add my own error. The input should be an int. Where should I do this? I have an objectdatasource with listview and I'm having trouble getting the textbox.text from the code behind so I can use tryParse.

Comment: This is not validation. If the value is wrong, it should never be set like you have in your code.

Comment: this property already accepts INT. What do you mean, by "validation".?

Comment: And what do you think it can be? Other than int

Comment: @leppie: This is perfectly good ViewModel code.

Comment: Int32.TryParse(...) ??

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your property is of type Int32. You cannot assign anything else than a valid integer to this property. Now if you have some user input which is under the form of a string and then you need to assign it to the integer property you could use the [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method to ensure that the value entered by the user is a valid integer.

For example:

```
string someValueEnteredByUser = ...
int value;
if (!int.TryParse(someValueEnteredByUser, out value))
{
    // the value entered by the user is not a valid integer
}
else
{
    // the value is a valid integer => you can use the value variable here
}
```

Comment: I *suppose* it's about *negative/non negative* stuff. But control on that already done... bah.

Answer (score 2):

`Number` is *always* an `int`, it is defined that way...

You probably want to validate the content of a string. Easiest way is to parse it into an `int`:

```
int number;

if(!int.TryParse(yourString, out number))
{
   Not an int!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'value' will always be of the same type as your variable. Thus having this:

```
private bool mabool = false; 

public bool MaBool
{
    get { return mabool; }
    set { mabool = value; }
}
```

Won't ever crash. This because, as I said, value will be the same type of the variable. In this case, value is a boolean.

Try it with a class:

```
public class Rotator
{
    public Roll, Pitch, Yaw;

    // Declarations here (...)
}

private Rotator rotation = new Rotator();
public Rotator Rotation
{
    get { return rotation; }
    set
    {
        // Since value is of the same type as our variable (Rotator)
        // then we can access it's components.
        if (value.Yaw > 180) // Limit yaw to a maximum of 180°
            value.Yaw = 180;
        else if (value.Yaw < -180) // Limit yaw to a minimum of -180°
            value.Yaw = -180;

        rotation = value;
    }
}
```

As seen on the second example, value is a Rotator, thus we can access it's components.